# Should I say "A or B is" or "A or B are"?

Tags: grammaticality

> The orange is selected if and only if the apple or grape **is/are**
>   selected.

May I ask whether using *is* or *are* is correct in the above sentence?

Answer (score 8):

An "apple or grape" is only one thing, so you would use *is* here.  If the list is mixed, you would use the plural: "if apples or a grape are selected" is correct. (Note also that it's necessary to use the *a* here, since we're mixing singular and plural list members.)
Also, "if an apple and grape are selected" is correct.

Comment: With reference(s), I think this answer will be perfect.

Comment: @holydragon Most of my answers come off the top of my head from what I use as a native English speaker, rather than what I have looked up in a reference.  So, if references are a criterion for a perfect answer, I will cheerfully admit that helpfulness, not perfection, is the goal of my answers. :)

Comment: @BobRodes Wouldn't this depend on mutual exclusivity? If A and B are not mutually exclusive, "A or B" would mean "A", "B", or "A and B". In this case, shouldn't we say, "A or B are"? However, if A and B are mutually exclusive, I would say "either A or B is". I think people often say "A or B" when they actually mean "either A or B". This is colloquially acceptable, but may be technically incorrect.

Comment: @user1992705 I don't think it does. I think colloquially people use "or" in the sense of logical `XOR` rather than logical `OR`, in other words *or* in the sense that excludes *and*. If I say that someone took an apple or a grape, I don't mean that he took both. If he took both, he took an apple *and* a grape. Can you give me an example of a sentence where "or" refers to logical `OR` and uses the plural? I can't think.of one, and your "A or B are" sounds strange to me.